# Getting Gmail message with Service Account by using PHP

Tags: php, api, gmail-api

I got a problem with Gmail API service account, I would like to get my personal email from Gmail API without ask for verifying Gmail account and password. Exactly it could be interested to get them from my back-end code.

I have tried to implement this function but it was not worked.

```
public function list_email()
    {
            $this->load->library('google');
            $client = new Google_Client();
            $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);  
            $client->setApplicationName('airxpress-message-api');

            $client_email = '867003685660-dk6896nclmfdql86cudt65q2c06f8ooa@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
            $private_key = file_get_contents(base_url().G_API.'p12/airxpress-message-api-45eb6393e620.p12');
            $scopes = array('https://mail.google.com/');

            $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
                $client_email,
                $scopes,
                $private_key
            );

            $credentials->sub = 'notifications-vd@gmail.com';  

            $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

            if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) 
            {
              $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
            }

            $messages = array();

            try 
            {
                $opt_param['labelIds'] = 'INBOX';

                $opt_param['q'] = 'subject:"reservation request"';

                $messagesResponse = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', $opt_param);

                if ($messagesResponse->getMessages())
                {
                    $messages = array_merge($messages, $messagesResponse->getMessages());
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception $e) 
            {
                print 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }

            print_r($messages);

    }
```

I met this message error :

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client", "error_description" : "Unauthorized client or scope in request." }''

So, I have gotten the reference from  :

```
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts
```

Could anyone tell me how to solve it?

Comment: Please describe your use case clearly. I didnot understand "I would like to get my personal email from Gmail API without ask for verifying Gmail account and password"?

Comment: DGC. I want to use Service Account in Gmail API, but it was not work for me.

Comment: You should do domain wide delegation to your service account, check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation. This will resolve your issue.